# Trying to use a timer in dart to run a function every few seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

I followed the documentation but it still doesn't work, here is the code:

```
void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
   scheduleTimeout(5 * 1000);
}

Timer scheduleTimeout([int milliseconds = 10000]) =>
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), handleTimeout);

void handleTimeout() {
   print("running *****************");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the timer after you call runApp that's why it's not working for you, just swipe the functions it will work.

```
void main() {
  scheduleTimeout(5 * 1000);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[Timer Document link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html)